# Normal reaction on a mass travelling along a curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I've come across a set of problems in classical mechanics, where I am supposed to find the value of the normal reaction that acts on a mass, as it travels along a curve $y=f(x)$.

For example, suppose we have a parabola $y=bx^2$, and a bead of mass $m$ is traveling along this parabola, with a constant speed given by $v=\sqrt{\frac{2g}{b}}$. I've been asked to find the normal reaction, about the origin $(0,0)$, in terms of $mg$.

First of all, is it even possible for the speed of the particle to be constant in this situation? There is no mention of friction or anything, and if I assume that the bead is moving under the influence of gravity, shouldn't the potential energy change, thus implying a change in kinetic energy and thus, velocity? Is velocity here the rate of change of $y$ against $x$?

However, assuming that the velocity does indeed remain constant, how do I approach the above problem. The given answer is $N=5mg$

In general, suppose I have a curve, and a value of velocity, which may or may not be constant, how exactly do I approach such problems where I'm asked to find normal reaction?

**EDIT:**

According to the comment and the answer, I've proceeded as follows :

$$k=\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{(1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Since, $y=bx^2$, $y''=2b$, and $y'=2bx.$

At $x,y=0$, we have $k=2b$.

Plugging this back, we have $N=mkv^2$, where $v=\sqrt{\frac{2g}{b}}$

Thus, we have :

$$N=4mg$$

The stated answer is however $N=5mg$. Am I missing something here, or is my solution correct ?

Comment: Thanks ! I used the formula to calculate the radius of curvature and thus the curvature at the origin, and it came out to be 2b. When I multiply this with mv2, I get 4mg as my answer. The stated answer is 5mg, so there is an extra mg term coming in from somewhere. I'm unable to find the source of that term. I'm adding my calculations to the question, if you'd like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the speed is constant for now, it can be shown that, the "radius of a curve" is calculated as:

$$\rho = \frac{(1+f'(x)^{\frac{3}{2}} )}{f''(x)}$$

This is probably something for you to figure out why.

Using that, you can calculate the first and second derivative, becoming $2bx$ and $2b$ respectively. inserting the value at the origin $x=0$, you can see the radius becomes $\frac{1}{2b}$. If you are familiar with writing Newton's second law in a circular motion, you can assume that for the small time where the particle is in a small part of your curve, the motion can be views as a particle moving in a circle (a small arc of that circle for that matter). This can be written as:

$$\frac{mv^2}{\rho} = N - mg$$

$$\frac{m\frac{2g}{b}}{\frac{1}{2b}} = N - mg$$

and from there you'll arrive at your final value.

> shouldn't the potential energy change, thus implying a change in kinetic energy and thus, velocity?

The only possible thing that comes through my mind is that in many academic test books, the hypothetical situation are there to make for an easy calculation. The person asking the question is probably keen to see you understand the basic math and basic intuitions behind, but of course every aspect of this question crumbles in real life, and you are right about your suspicions.

EDIT: in fact, this is how one goes about solving most of those questions asking you to find the point of separation for a ball rolling down a curve and such.

Comment: Thank you so much. In your second equation, I believe $2b$ should be in the numerator instead. That being said, this question seems extremely wrong if one thinks about it. For example, I don't think we can assume constant velocity if we let gravity act on our body. If gravity works on the mass, then we get that extra $mg$ term in the equation, that gives such an answer. But this is paradoxical as we initially assumed that velocy is constant. That wouldn't be true, if we allow gravity to work.

Comment: I hope that reasoning is correct. I too think that this was done to see if we are good at calculations and nothing else. Even if we ignore the real world, by pure theory this problem is wrong. We either ignore gravity or ignore constant speed. We can't assume both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there is gravity then the particle will change its speed. Newton's second law on a tangent normal basis in this case yields

${\bf F} = m (\dot{v} {\bf e}_t + \kappa v^2 {\bf e}_n)$

If the track is frictionless and there is no gravity, then ${\bf F} \cdot {\bf e}_t = 0$ and we have proved that $\dot{v} = 0$. So the speed would stay constant in the case of no gravity.

The normal force ${\bf N} = N {\bf e}_n$ acts normal to the curve. Therefore, $N = m \kappa v^2$.

We know that $v$ stays constant with no gravity. So the question is: Do you know how to find $\kappa(x)$ for a plane curve of the form $y = f(x)$? Maybe look into that first.

Comment: Thanks ! I used the formula to calculate the radius of curvature and thus the curvature at the origin, and it came out to be $2b$. When I multiply this with $mv^2$, I get $4mg$ as my answer. The stated answer is $5mg$, so there is an extra $mg$ term coming in from somewhere.  I'm unable to find the source of that term. I'm adding my calculations to the question, if you'd like to see.

Comment: In that case then there is gravity. The speed should not be constant, so I am not sure of your problem statement.